# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

I had published around 9-10 messages in server.But few of them didn't published successfully.It is giving following error in log.Please help me with it.I am not getting which part of program is giving this problem

log-

```
 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (WorkManager(2)-4) Transaction (Process ID 112) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.


2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1065.invoke(Unknown Source)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_386555905.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_386555905.java)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_386555905.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_386555905.java)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)

***2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [com.rt1.ejb.dao.DataHandler] (WorkManager(2)-4) insertHistory(HistoryBean historyBean)org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert: 
some entity name***

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)

2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
2016-08-02 17:25:22,449 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkManager(2)-31)  at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the problem Look for any possible deadlock. Which Database you are using? Is it a multithreaded environment?

set below two properties of Hibernate

hibernate.order_updates=true

hibernate.order_inserts=true

Comment: I am using sql database

Comment: I am assuming you are using sql server database use sp_who command to  check the lock tables.